# { parser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now treat it as { parser: "babel" }

Tags: vue.js, babel

A la hora de cargar mi proyecto vue en el navegador me sale este problema:
 **{ parser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now treat it as { parser: "babel" }**.
 La página me carga, pero en blanco y con el html vacío. Antes funcionaba perfectamente. No se como poder solucionar este problema.

Answer (score -1):

Este problema usualmente esta relacionado con el vue-loader, actualiza la version de este paquete e intenta de nuevo